# PGSQL pgcompacttable on windows

Tags: postgresql, perl

I have a big PGSQL database and need to reclaim some disk space.PGSQL is version 13.2, running on Windows.

I have found several posts which state you can use pgcompacttable on a windows PGSQL and i tried following it.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389509/how-to-use-pg-squeeze-on-windows

I have 0 experience with Perl.
I keep getting compilation errors on the 'DBI package'.

Anyone got this to work on a windows PGSQL? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're mixing up [pg_compactable](https://github.com/dataegret/pgcompacttable) with pg_squeeze. I checked the pg_squeeze git repo and there's no perl code in it - `C` and some Python, but no perl. Can you not just run `CLUSTER` or `VACUUM FULL` instead? There are the extensions [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) and [pg_squeeze](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/pg_squeeze/) - but I believe that these only work on *nix (not absolutely sure on this).

Comment: Windows is not considered to be a first class citizen - the major target for PostgreSQL users would be *nixen and many extensions (AFAICS) don't/won't work with Windows. Have you tried with a source distribution? What distro are you using?

Comment: Correct, pgcompacttable requires Perl DBI library being installed. I'm a pgcompacttable committer, but I don't use windows and can't tell you how to install perl modules. But there is one idea: unlike pg_repack, pgcompacttable does not need its own extension in the database, just the standard contrib pgstattuple. Therefore, you can run pgcompacttable over the network from some linux host.

Comment: @Melkij - you might want to make that an answer?

Comment: @Melkij thanks for your answer.
I don't have a linux in the network of that customer. I'll look into it.

Vacuum full is not an option, table is 2.7 TB big and i don't have 3TB more disk space.

Comment: @Vérace, probably not. I don't think this would be a "good answer" to this question. Good comment/alternative, but not an answer.